# Escaping strings in associative arrays (bash)

Tags: bash, string, escape-characters

I am writing a script which executes a number of programs with arguments. To simplify it as much as possible, consider the following example:

```
programs=( "ls" "echo" )
declare -A parameters
parameters["ls"]="-l /tmp/foo"
parameters["echo"]="Hello"

for program in "${programs[@]}"
do
  $program ${parameters[$program]}
done
```

This works fine as long as there are no spaces in the arguments. Of course, escaping strings has been discussed before, so I tried all of the different ways I could find here on StackExchange and some other pages. However, I could not find a solution which works in my case which uses associative arrays. For example, when I want to get a listing of "/tmp/foo bar", neither this

```
parameters["ls"]="-l /tmp/foo bar"
```

nor this

```
parameters["ls"]="-l \"/tmp/foo bar\""
```

nor this

```
parameters["ls"]="-l /tmp/foo\ bar"
```

works as expected. Similarly, putting quotes around the program call in the loop

```
  $program "${parameters[$program]}"
```

does not work either, since the two parameters (-l and the path) are interpreted as one parameter.

I found the closest thing to a solution in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166078/shell-string-escape-for-command-arguments) which proposes using multiple separate variables, one for each argument, for the program call. This, however, is not possible in my use case which requires a variable number of arguments for each program - thus my use of the associative array.

Is there any other way to escape the path name?

Best regards
Andreas

Comment: You'll want bi-dimensional arrays if you want to store several arguments (ksh93, not bash), or use some form of encoding (like `printf %q ` output with `eval`). But sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Forgive my stupid question, but what is an "XY problem"?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @jasonwryan: Thanks. I am writing a script to grade student submissions in a semi-automated way. For that, I need every program (task) of the submission to be executed with pre-defined parameters and to evaluate the results. Everything works fine so far, but I cannot use spaces in the path due to the issues described above, which is really annoying (my existing folder structure contains folder names with spaces). I am not quite sure whether the context I just provided helps solving the problem - avoiding the "XY problem", if I understood the explanation you linked to correctly.

Comment: @StéhaneChezales You can get something like 2d arrays in `bash`.  If you do a separate array per 2cd dimension element and `!`nameref for each in an indexed array... hacky, and `[indexing]` doesnt work but `sli:ci:ng` does. But i agree that there is probably a better way to go about this. andreas: `bash` is not a db, you know. It's a command interpreter - and not even among the better ones - you really shouldnt be stacking so much state in its env like that. If your problem is your dir tree has spaces and shouldnt - maybe look to removing the spaces.

Comment: @mikeserv: Yes, I already worked around by renaming my folders, but I thought that I am just missing something in the documentation or while searching on how to escape properly.

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger - probably not. Its not easy to do - and probably not worth doing. Pretty messy overall

Comment: @mikeserv it was actually fun to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create an array with the parameters.

Then, store the array string value (found with `declare -p`) at `parameters`, and recover and use it as an actual array later on like in:

```
#!/bin/bash

programs=( "ls" "echo" )
declare -A parameters

arrayTmp=("-l" "/tmp/foo bar")
parameters["ls"]="`declare -p arrayTmp |sed -r "s,[^=]*='(.*)'$,\1,"`"

parameters["echo"]="Hello"

for program in "${programs[@]}";do
    echo "PROGRAM: $program"
    declare -a arrayTmp="${parameters[$program]}"
    $program "${arrayTmp[@]}"
    arrayTmp=()
done
```

Comment: Nice - that seems to do the trick. Thank you.